# When clicking contact form 7 submit button, I would like to clean the Woocommerce cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm using Wordpress Avada theme. When I click on the Submit form, I want to clear the cart.
 [image: Screenshot here]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: When I click on the contact form submit button then clear Woocommerce cart.
Check the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8oSb.png

Comment: What You want to do? When a user clicks on submit button on contact form 7 you want to clear the current cart items?

Comment: Yes I want to clear the current cart items?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code this will work for you.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
});
```

Comment: People like to understand why it would work. If possible, give some more details to your answer.

Comment: Please add above code in your theme  function.php file